Show that $\sin(z+w) = \sin(z)\cos(w) + \cos(z)\sin(w)$ using Taylor series
The following two identities,
$$
\sin(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^k z^{2k + 1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$
and
$$
(z + w)^p = \sum_{j=0}^p \binom{ 2p + 1} j z^j w^{p-j}
$$
are used in the provided solution
$$
\begin{aligned} \sin (z+w) & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(z+w)^{2 k+1}}{(2 k+1)!} \\ & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \sum_{j=0}^{2 k+1}\binom{\color{red}{2 k+1}}{j} \frac{z^j w^{2 k+1-j}}{(2 k+1)!} \\ & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \sum_{j=0}^{2 k+1} \frac{1}{j!(2 k+1-j)!} z^j w^{2 k+1-j} \\ & =\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^j}{j!} \sum_{k:\; 2 k+1 \geq j}(-1)^k \frac{1}{(2 k+1-j)!} w^{2 k+1-j} .\end{aligned}
$$
Questions

Is the red part above, $\binom{\color{red}{2k + 1}}j$, a typo? Should it not be $ \binom{2(2k + 1) + 1} j$ as $p = 2k + 1$? Or is the provided identity wrong? Maybe it should look like this: $(z + w)^p = \sum_{j=0}^p \binom{p} j z^j w^{p-j}$

How can we justify the jump from the third to the final row?


That is, how do we pull a
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \dots \sum_{k:\; 2 k+1 \geq j} \dots
$$
out of a
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dots \sum_{j=0}^{2k+1} \dots
$$
The solution goes on in the following way, for reference:

When $j$ is even, say $j = 2n$, then $2k + 1 \geq j$ means precisely $k \geq n$. So the term with $j = 2n$ is
$$\begin{aligned} \frac{z^{2 n}}{(2 n)!} \sum_{k \geq n}(-1)^k \frac{1}{(2 k+1-2 n)!} w^{2 k+1-2 n} & =\frac{z^{2 n}}{(2 n)!} \sum_{k \geq n}(-1)^{m+n} \frac{1}{(2 m+1)!} w^{2 m+1} \\ & =\frac{z^{2 n}}{(2 n)!}(-1)^n \sin (w)\end{aligned}$$
where at the second to last step we made the change of variables $m = k - n$. A similar argument shows that when $j$ is odd, say $j = 2n + 1$, then the term with $j = 2n + 1$ is
$$\frac{z^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)!}(-1)^n \cos (w)$$
Combining these things, we get
$$\begin{aligned} \sin (z+w) & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2 n}}{(2 n)!}(-1)^n \sin (w)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)!}(-1)^n \cos (w) \\ & =\cos (z) \sin (w)+\sin (z) \cos (w) .\end{aligned}$$


The red part is not a typo. The binomial theorem states that
$$
(z + w)^p = \sum_{j=0}^p \binom{p}{j} z^j w^{p-j}. 
$$
Notice how the exponents of $z$ and $w$ sum to $p$ in each term. Sometimes it's actually easier to see what's going on by using a pair of indices $i$ and $j$ such that $i + j = p$ with the understanding that $i \geq 0$ so $j \leq p$ and $j \geq 0$ so $i \leq p$. Then the sum looks like
$$
(z + w)^p = \sum_{i+j=p} \binom{p}{j} z^j w^i 
= \sum_{i+j=p} \frac{p!}{i!\,j!} z^j w^i. 
$$
In the usual formula, this symmetry is broken by choosing one index $i$ that runs from $0$ up to $p$ while its "dual" index $j = p - i$ runs from $p$ down to $0$.
When we apply this identity in the context of the Maclaurin series for sine,
$p = 2k + 1$, so
$$
(z + w)^{2k+1} = \sum_{j=0}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}{j} z^j w^{2k+1-j}. 
$$

In the final step of the calculation, order of summation is reversed. This is valid, provided that the sums converge absolutely,${}^\dagger$ and they do.
Why do the upper and lower bounds of the indices look that way? There's a discrete infinite triangle of possibilities, and you can either read off the indices by (row, col) or by (col, row), just making sure that each one is included exactly once. In this figure, the horizontal axis is $p = 2k + 1$ and the vertical axis is $j$.

If we read by columns, then we pick a column corresponding to $0 \leq k$ with no upper bound and for each $k$, we include those $j$ satisfying $0 \leq j \leq 2k+1$. Alternatively, if we read by rows, then we pick a row $0 \leq j$ with no upper bound and for each $j$, we include those $k$ satisfying $j \leq 2k+1$ with no upper bound. Notice that when taken in pairs, these constraints describe precisely the same set of indices:
$$
\left\{ (k, j) \in \mathbb{Z} \;\middle|\; \begin{matrix} 
0 \phantom{{}\leq j} \leq 2k+1 \\ 
0 \leq j \leq 2k+1 
\end{matrix} \right\} 
= 
\left\{ (k, j) \in \mathbb{Z} \;\middle|\; \begin{matrix} 
0 \leq j \phantom{{}\leq 2k+1} \\ 
\phantom{0 \leq {}} j \leq 2k+1 
\end{matrix} \right\} 
$$

${}^\dagger\!$ This is a discrete version of Fubini's theorem for integrals. Have a look at the final paragraph of the Introduction section here.

I edited my answer to include more about the reindexing.

What did you use to make the grid image ?

Desmos, @jimjim.
